# Cannot deserialize a JSON object in Xamarin Forms with JSON.net

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, json.net, cross-platform

I am having trouble deserializing a JSON that comes from an API call in my Android project. Yet when I reference the shared library (.NET Standard strategy) in a Unit Test project and test the code - everything works and my model is populated correctly. Using [Preserve(AllMembers = true)] does not help.

These are my models:

```
public class StockQuotesResultDto
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Stock Quotes")]
    public StockQuoteDto[] StockQuotes { get; set; }
}

//[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

//[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class StockQuoteDto
{
    [JsonProperty("1. symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

}
```

This is the JSON I am trying to deserialize:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Batch Stock Market Quotes",
        "2. Notes": "IEX Real-Time Price provided for free by IEX (https://iextrading.com/developer/).",
        "3. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Stock Quotes": [
        {
            "1. symbol": "MSFT",
            "2. price": "100.2500",
            "3. volume": "--",
            "4. timestamp": "2018-06-22 15:59:57"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "FB",
            "2. price": "201.4100",
            "3. volume": "--",
            "4. timestamp": "2018-06-22 15:59:59"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "AAPL",
            "2. price": "185.3900",
            "3. volume": "--",
            "4. timestamp": "2018-06-22 16:01:08"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code I use to deserialize:

```
StockQuotesResultDto stockQuotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockQuotesResultDto>(contentAsString);
```

When I debug my application on my phone, all properties of StockQuotesResultDto are null (note that the result is properly retrieved from the REST API call). Yet when I debug my test that executes the very same code - everything is fine. I just started playing with Xamarin and am at a complete loss. I read a bunch of threads here and other forums but could not find a solution. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Check if you have json.net nuget installed in Android project not only shared project.

Comment: Thanks for the input Nick. I have missed that and tried it just now, unfortunately it does not work...

Comment: so when you debug on phone the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws no exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions whatsoever. Just the properties of the resulting objects are all with null values. In the test project, they are all properly populated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I have found a "solution" to my problem.
As it turns out, the problem only occurs when I debug my application on my device via Xamarin live link. **If I run it on the emulator - everything is fine**. This acceptable for now as Im just playing around. It would be interesting whether it runs fine when it is properly deployed on a device.

Edit: when debugged on the device, but without Xamarin Live it works ok as well. As it turns out the problem occurs only through Xamarin Live link.

Comment: Are you referring to Xamarin Live Player when you say "Xamarin Live Link"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, sorry

Comment: Thanks @ChrisNicksonPrime! I’ll share your feedback internally with the Xamarin Live Player team!